# Javascript changing code for reading modified object

Tags: javascript

I have some code that's already working but I need to change the object structure and I need to modify the code so it works again.

Here is the working code (with the original object data):

```
obj = {
    "category": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "category": "1",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "category": "1",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "category": "2",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "category": "2",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "category": "3",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
    ]
}

var results = [ ];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.category.length; i++) {

    $.each( obj.category[i].tags, function( key, value ) {
      results.push(value);
    });

}

var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(results, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});

console.log(uniqueNames);
```

I now need to change the object to look like this structure:

```
obj = {
        "id": "1",
        "category": "1",
        "tags": {
            "483": "tag1",
            "484": "tag2"
        }
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myfiddles2016/qte5oa9g/2/)

So, basically  the category has been taken out.

How can i get it to work with my new object structure?

*Note: The code is supposed to get all the tag names available, then remove duplicates and finally add the result to an array*

Comment: Looks like the only thing that changed is you don't have to loop over `obj.category`. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: At least, be clear : give us the input object and what you expect as output

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle link that shows the problem

Comment: That looks like just `obj.category[0]`. Since it's not an array, it can't hold more than one object.

Comment: Please put all relevant code here, not at jsfiddle. This question makes no sense with just the posted code, since it doesn't say what you need to do with the object. There's no need to use jsfiddle, SO has built-in stack snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/qte5oa9g/8/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  objArr = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "category": "1",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "category": "1",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "category": "2",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "category": "2",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "category": "3",
            "tags": {
                "483": "tag1",
                "484": "tag2"
            }
        },
    ];


var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {

    $.each( objArr, function( key, value ) {
      (value.tags) ? results.push(value) : false;

    });
    console.log(results);

}

var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(results, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});

console.log(uniqueNames);

}); //onready end
```

Okay. So firstly, maybe you have some sort of rationality as to why, but if you're going to hold a list of objects I feel that you SHOULD have a container like "categories" or store them in an array.

In my example I changed the object to an object array.

From there you just need to check the array.length and set the index that you're checking to the object array instead of the inner object like you had it.

There's a specific object used to gather unique values called Set(). It pretty much makes your uniqueNames thing useless, so I removed it entirely and just invoked results as a Set() and logged it.

Instead of pushing to a set you simply use the .add(value) method. I listed a reference for it below as well as to Arrays.

If you have any questions please feel free to ask.

References:

[MDN: Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

[MDN: Set Prototype Add Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add)

[MDN: JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/object)

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).ready()` in a function that makes no use of the DOM?

Comment: @Barmar It's part of OP's code in the fiddle he set up.

Comment: Sorry but there's no result in the console. The code should get all the tag names available, then remove duplicates and finally add the result to an array

Comment: @MarkcccAppellido There is a result in the console, it's under a Set Object. If you would like to see the results specifically you could log results.values() or if you would really like them in an array format you could iterate through them and add them to an array using a pattern like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hy46u7ey/ - at this point though, I would expect you to look for an answer and try to resolve the problem you're having before asking further questions.

Comment: Sorry I just get " Set {}" as a results. The expected result would be ["tag1", "tag2"]

Comment: It's almost there...it's just not removing duplicates

Comment: @MarkcccAppellido the Set object doesn't allow duplicates